What is a "shared object" in the context of installing a package?
I am trying to install a package through Github via devtools in R:
devtools::install_github("daewoooo/SVbyEye", branch = "master")
but I keep getting the error:
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/V8/libs/V8.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/V8/libs/V8.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZNSt3__122__libcpp_verbose_abortEPKcz'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImport -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘SVbyEye’
* removing ‘/Users/will/Library/R/arm64/4.4/library/SVbyEye’
Warning messages:
1: In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/0z/42j_n0qn3yjf7rgv47rgj9d80000gn/T//RtmpRhdVn7/file90c578a88b7/SVbyEye_0.99.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
2: In devtools::install_github("daewoooo/SVbyEye", branch = "master") :
  Arguments in `...` must be used.
✖ Problematic argument:
• branch = "master"
ℹ Did you misspell an argument name?

Here are some details on what I am running this on:
R version 4.4.2 (2024-10-31)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20
Running under: macOS Ventura 13.2.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib 
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib;  LAPACK version 3.12.0

Edit: It looks like there is something wrong with the library path or compiler compatibility  ~ % ls /Users/will/Library/R/arm64/4.4/library/V8/libs/V8.so ls: /Users/will/Library/R/arm64/4.4/library/V8/libs/V8.so: No such file or directory
~ % cat ~/.R/Makevars CXXFLAGS = -std=c++17
Does anyone have any idea what might be going on here? I have freshly updated R and Rstudio.

Try installing V8 through R (using Sys.setenv(DOWNLOAD_STATIC_LIBV8 = 1); install.packages("V8")) then start a new R session and retry the SVbyEye install and see if you get the same error

Thanks so much for this suggestion. Unfortunately I still got the same error. After trying as you suggested I ran library("V8") and it said this: Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘V8’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):  unable to load shared object '/Users/will/Library/R/arm64/4.4/library/V8/libs/V8.so':   dlopen(/Users/will/Library/R/arm64/4.4/library/V8/libs/V8.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '__ZNSt3__122__libcpp_verbose_abortEPKcz' 
Maybe there is something weird going on with my library?

Yep, if you have homebrew installed, try installing V8 via homebrew (brew install V8) or you could try installing from source (https://v8.dev/docs / https://v8.dev/docs/compile-arm64) but it looks 'complicated'

Hmm, ok I installed V8 with homebrew but I still get the same error when I call library(V8). Do you have any other suggestions? I really appreciate the help.

Does the library exist where R is looking for it @Will? I.e. if you type ls /Users/will/Library/R/arm64/4.4/library/V8/libs/V8.so in a terminal do you find the file? If you have a "~/.R/Makevars" file can you please edit your question with the contents i.e. in a terminal type cat ~/.R/Makevars and paste the output into your question. The LDFLAGS might provide a clue as to why R can't find/load the library.

Thanks Jared. I edited the question. It looks like the library isn't there.

After an update of the macOS, xcode command line tools, V8 could be installed, and the package installation that I initially wanted worked. Thank you jared!

Awesome! I’m glad you solved it - it seemed as if something was very wrong, but I wasn’t sure what, and it was going to be very hard to troubleshoot as it installed on my system without issue. Can you please answer your own question (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20a%20question,on%20a%20Stack%20Exchange%20site.)

An update to MacOS sequoia 15.1.1 along with an update of xcode command line tools seemed to do the trick. After updating those, I was able to install V8 and then SVbyEye.
